# How to turn on Networked Computer by using WOL (Wake on Lan) C# or Java

Tags: c#, network-programming, bios, wake-on-lan, netbios

Can u please give me full code to turn on networked computer by WOL option of Network Card and BIOS.

Please provide me all the details and please try to give me working code.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;

//we derive our class from a standart one

public class WOLClass:UdpClient    
{
    public WOLClass():base()
    { }
    //this is needed to send broadcast packet

    public void SetClientToBrodcastMode()    
    {
      if(this.Active)
       this.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
                                 SocketOptionName.Broadcast,0);
    }
 }    

private void WakeFunction(string MAC_ADDRESS)   
     {
          WOLClass client=new WOLClass();
          client.Connect(new 
             IPAddress(0xffffffff),  //255.255.255.255  i.e broadcast

             0x2fff); // port=12287 let's use this one 

          client.SetClientToBrodcastMode();
          //set sending bites

          int counter=0;
          //buffer to be send

          byte[] bytes=new byte[1024];   // more than enough :-)

         //first 6 bytes should be 0xFF

         for(int y=0;y<6;y++)
            bytes[counter++]=0xFF;
         //now repeate MAC 16 times

         for(int y=0;y<16;y++)
         {
             int i=0;
             for(int z=0;z<6;z++)
             {
                  bytes[counter++]= 
                      byte.Parse(MAC_ADDRESS.Substring(i,2),
                      NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                  i+=2;
             }
         }

         //now send wake up packet

         int reterned_value=client.Send(bytes,1024);
     }
```

[See more here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/cswol.aspx)